# Is there a more efficient way to query a mongodb collection and normalize the result?

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, pymongo, plotly-dash

I am creating a Dash app that initially queries a MongoDB collection (around 200k documents), performs json_normalize then does some pandas manipulations and finally plots a few graphs in a dashboard. However, the first two steps seem to be very time and memory consuming with respect to the rest.

My code looks like this:

```
games_collection = db.MatchFinishedEvent

results = games_collection.find({"$and": [{"match.season": {"$eq" : 6}}, {"result.players":{"$exists": True}}]},
                                 {"match.players.country": 1, "match.players.queueTime": 1,
                                  "match.startTime" : 1, "match.players.userId" : 1,
                                  "match.players.mmr.rating" : 1,"match.players.faction": 1,
                                  "match.players.updatedMmr.rating" : 1, "match.gameMode": 1,
                                  "match.players.won": 1, "match.players.ranking.leagueOrder" : 1,
                                  "match.players.ranking.rank" : 1,
                                  "result.players.userId" : 1, "match.players.updatedRanking.leagueOrder" : 1,
                                  "match.players.updatedRanking.rank" : 1,
                                  "result.mapInfo.elapsedGameTimeTotalSeconds" :1,
                                  "result.players.overallScore" : 1, "result.player.won" : 1})

s6_result = []

batch = 2000
results.rewind()
results.batch_size(batch)
for r in results:
    s6_result.append(r)

result = pd.json_normalize(s6_result, ['result', 'players'], [['_id'],
                                                              ['result', 'mapInfo', 'elapsedGameTimeTotalSeconds']])
match = pd.json_normalize(s6_result, ['match', 'players'],
                          [['_id'], ['match', 'gameMode'], ['match', 'startTime']])
del s6_result

df2 = result.merge(match, on=['_id', 'userId'])
del result
del match
```

One such document, prior to json_normalize, looks like this:

```
{'_id': 'abc',
 'match': {'gameMode': 1,
           'players': [{'userId': 'xxx',
                        'country': 'BR',
                        'mmr': {'rating': 1500},
                        'queueTime': 0,
                        'faction': 4,
                        'ranking': {'rank': -1},
                        'updatedMmr': {'rating': 1586.9114300769133},
                        'updatedRanking': {'rank': -1},
                        'won': True},
                       {'userId': 'yyy',
                        'country': 'RU',
                        'mmr': {'rating': 1500},
                        'queueTime': 2,
                        'faction': 1,
                        'ranking': {'rank': -1},
                        'updatedMmr': {'rating': 1413.0952060220995},
                        'updatedRanking': {'rank': -1},
                        'won': False}],
           'startTime': 1614953613446.0},
 'result': {'mapInfo': {'elapsedGameTimeTotalSeconds': 2},
            'players': [{'userId': 'xxx',
                         'overallScore': {'SCORE1': 0,
                                          'SCORE2': 0,
                                          'SCORE3': 825,
                                          'SCORE4': 825}},
                        {'userId': 'yyy',
                         'overallScore': {'SCORE1': 0,
                                          'SCORE2': 0,
                                          'SCORE3': 965,
                                          'SCORE4': 965}}]}}
```

For the json_normalize I'm facing an issue anyway, as I am unable to flatten the 'result' and the 'match' keys together and need to do it separately and then merge. The json_normalize as you can see flattens one document into two instances e.g.

```
userId, SCORE1, SCORE2, SCORE3, SCORE4, _id, result.mapInfo.elapsedGameTimeTotalSeconds, country, queueTime... etc
xxx, 0, 0, 825, 825, abc, 2, BR, 0,...
yyy, 0, 0, 965, 965, abc, 2, RU, 2,...
```

or in short one row for each player with their individual field values (e.g. SCORE1, SCORE2) and  with common fields being present in both (_id, elapsedGameTimeTotalSeconds,gamemode etc). However, the above is just an example as there are also documents that have more than 2 players i.e. 4 players or 8 players

So my question is: can I query the MongoDB with pymongo but use something more efficient than a list and a for loop? Can I achieve flattening the file without the need of using json_normalize after the query?
Can I do both??

I believe there must be some application of the aggregation pipeline to achieve the latter, but I am not sure how to use it to flatten the documents the way I described above.

Comment: Could you please share the final document shape expected here?

Comment: Hello @GBackMania, I described the shape of the final result above. However you can use the document I showed as an example and apply the result, match and merge and you will have the final result. Let me know if that helps or whether you need anything else

Comment: Your query filter `{"match.season": {"$eq" : 6}}` can perform better if there is an index on the `match.season` field. Generally, indexes can help improve performance (and there are many other factors that affect a query''s performance). You can check your query's performance by generating a _query plan_, using the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/).